# Problems with migration from one CoreData model to another

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I created new version of CoreData model (added one new attribute to entity) and mapping from one to another. Then I open document created with old model. It opens normally but when I tried to save it I get alert window with "**The document “Blahblahblah” could not be saved as “Blahblahblah.blah”. An error occurred while saving.**" and message in debug console

```
AppKit called rmdir("/private/var/folders/v9/y2tl4yh55zj1pcg0typksyrm0000gp/T/TemporaryItems/(A Document Being Saved By Document 3)"), it didn't return 0, and errno was set to 66.
```

Have you got ideas what is it meen?

PS. It is not my first experience in CoreData migration but it's first time I stuck so hard.

Comment: I'm getting the same error message while saving a document based application, but I'm not using Core Data at all. I think it's going wrong while writing a dictionary to a file. Did you ever find out what happened in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mileage may vary, but when I had this issue, it turned out to be a validation error.

My use case was an autosave (i.e. I hadn't explicitly called save). I verified this by explicitly putting a save call in and dumping the resultant error:

```
NSError* error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  abort();
}
```

Turns out (in my case), I had a required entity that wasn't being set.

Good luck.